# Was there any reference to Shigure's brother before Chapter 545?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

This chapter came to me as a real shocker. I always thought Shigure was an only child. As the title says, were there any references or perhaps even hints or foreshadowing that Shigure had a brother?

Comment: I'm about to reread the whole manga...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a reference when Akisame dropped off Shigure at the Kousaka household.
It was confusing, however, because at the time, we learned of her so called "brother" as Kousaka's number 1 apprentice. Therefore he is not actually her brother by family register.

Chapter 545 has Shigure calling him Nii-san (for the first time), which made me think he was actually the son of Kousaka when he really wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since he knows Kosaka style, I want to say he's the biological son of her adoptive father, Hachirobe Kosaka. Pretty sure he alluded to his son being dead.

Comment: I have no recollection of this whatsoever, partially because I never really paid that much attention to this series. But let's talk about the mouse since the brother seems to know him. Did that mouse first show up from Shigure's real father or adoptive father? Also, would you happen to have the chapter where it was stated that the adoptive father's son was dead?